# Standard fonts size to be followed

Tags: android, android-activity

What standard size of Buttons and Text view and Edit text should be followed for          all mobiles while making applications ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html

This will help you to choose size for widgets ..

Also refer this 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guideline mentioned by google in material design. Yo can find them here https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field for text fields and https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-usage for buttons.